# redirect default '/' to a specific path nuxt / netlify

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, vue-router

Basically I want the root route `'/'` to be redirected to my `'/home'` route.

My Nuxt app is hosted on Netlify so I tried to do this is the `_redirects` file

```
/ /home
```

as per their redirect docs - but it's not working.

Now I know that in Vue in the router config you can set up redirects, but how do I achieve the same thing in Nuxt??

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your main `index.vue` page you would add:

```
<script>
  export default {
    middleware: 'redirect'
  }
</script>
```

Then you would create a middleware to actually redirect to desired page, in middleware > `redirect.js`:

```
export default function ({ store, redirect }) {
  return redirect('/home')
}
```